# The isomorphism $H^1(X;\mathbb Z_2) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(X),\mathbb Z_2)$ and $w_1(E)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

On page $87$ of Hatcher's book [*Vector Bundles and K-Theory*](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) it states that, assuming $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex ($X$ is connected), there are  isomorphisms

$$H^1(X;\mathbb Z_2) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(H_1(X),\mathbb Z_2)  \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(X),\mathbb Z_2).$$

My questions:

1. We can directly calculate the first cohomology group with $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients from the fundamental group. A simple example is if $\pi_1(X)=\mathbb Z$, then $H^1(X;\mathbb Z_2)=\mathbb Z_2$, or if $\pi_1(X)=\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$, then $H^1(X;\mathbb Z_2)=\mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2$. Are these statements correct?
2. Is there any restriction to this isomorphisms? Assuming that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex seems very general to me, i.e. any topological manifold is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex.
3. Does it mean actually the first Stiefel-Whitney class $w_1(E)\in H^1(M;\mathbb Z_2)$ of a real vector bundle $E$ can always be computed (using pullback) from the $w_1(E|_\mathcal L)$ of non-contractible loops $\mathcal L \in M$ (where $M$ is the base space)? That is, if I know $w_1(E|_\mathcal L)$ of all (nonequivalent) non-contractible loops $\mathcal L$, do I know $w_1(E)$? If so, does this conclusion need isomorphism $H^1(X;\mathbb Z_2) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(X),\mathbb Z_2)$, or do we just need to use the pullback to prove it is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out, your computations are correct. As for the assumptions, I actually don't think they are necessary. The first isomorphism comes from the Universal Coefficient Theorem, and the second is a consequence of the Hurewicz Theorem. Now let me address your third question.

The isomorphism $H^1(X; \mathbb{Z}_2) \to \operatorname{Hom}(H_1(X; \mathbb{Z}), \mathbb{Z}_2)$ takes the form $[\alpha] \mapsto \Phi_{[\alpha]}$ where $\Phi_{[\alpha]} : H_1(X; \mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ is given by $\Phi_{[\alpha]}([c]) = \langle[\alpha], [c]\rangle = \alpha(c)$.

The isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(H_1(X; \mathbb{Z}), \mathbb{Z}_2) \to \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(X), \mathbb{Z}_2)$ takes the form $\Phi \mapsto \Phi'$ where $\Phi' : \pi_1(X) \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ is given by $\Phi'([f]) = \Phi(f_*[S^1])$.

Combining, we see that the isomorphism $H^1(X; \mathbb{Z}_2) \to \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(X), \mathbb{Z}_2)$ takes the form $[\alpha] \mapsto \Phi_{[\alpha]}'$ where $\Phi_{[\alpha]}' : \pi_1(X) \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ is given by $\Phi_{[\alpha]}'([f]) = \Phi_{[\alpha]}(f_*[S^1]) = \langle[\alpha], f_*[S^1]\rangle = \langle f^*[\alpha], [S^1]\rangle$.

Now if $E \to X$ is a vector bundle, then $w_1(E) \in H^1(X; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ corresponds to $\Phi_{w_1(E)}' : \pi_1(X) \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ which is given by $\Phi_{w_1(E)}'([f]) = \langle f^*w_1(E), [S^1]\rangle = \langle w_1(f^*E), [S^1]\rangle$. So we can determine $\Phi_{w_1(E)}'$, and hence $w_1(E)$, from $w_1(f^*E)$ for every $[f] \in \pi_1(X)$.

Note that $w_1(f^*E) \in H^1(S^1; \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, and since a vector bundle over $S^1$ is trivial if and only if its first Stiefel-Whitney class vanishes, we see that $\Phi_{w_1(E)}'([f]) = 0$ if and only if $f^*E$ is trivial. Therefore, $w_1(E) = 0$ if and only if $f^*E$ is trivial for all $[f] \in \pi_1(X)$, i.e. $E$ is orientable if and only if its pullback to every loop is trivial.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you very much for the answer. What does $f_∗$ mean in $\Phi' ([f])=\Phi(f_*[S^1])$? Is $\Phi(f_*[S^1])\in H_1(X)$ correct?

Comment: Note that $[f] \in \pi_1(X)$, so $f : S^1 \to X$. Then $f_*$ denotes the induced map on homology $f_* : H_1(S^1) \to H_1(X)$, while $[S^1]$ denotes the fundamental homology class of $S^1$ which is a generator of $H_1(S^1)$. So $f_*[S^1] \in H_1(X)$. As $\Phi \in \operatorname{Hom}(H_1(X), \mathbb{Z}_2)$, we have $\Phi(f_*[S^1]) \in \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the explanation and the effort on editing the question. (1) Is the fundamental group part necessary? I suppose we don't need $\Phi'[f]=\Phi(f_*[S^1])$.  We can directly use $\Phi_{w_1(E)}(f_*[S^1])=<w_1(E),f_*[S^1]>=w_1(E|_{[S^1]})$.  (ps: which one is correct, $w_1(E|_{[S^1]})$ or  $w_1(E|_{S^1})$? ).  (2) It doesn't matter $[S^1]=1$ or $-1$, because the 'loop' $S^1$ we use doesn't have the winding direction, also due to $w_1[E|_{[S^1]}]\in \mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: (3)Why $\Phi_{[α]}([c])=\langle[\alpha],[c]\rangle=\alpha(c)$? (4) Why $\langle [\alpha],f_*[S^1]\rangle = \langle f^*[\alpha], [S^1]\rangle$? (5) Could we write an explicit function of $w_1(E)$ from $w_1(E|_{[S^1]})=\langle w_1(E),f_∗[S^1]\rangle $? i.e. $w_1(E)=....$. Sorry for so many questions. I really appreciate your taking time to answer my questions.

Comment: [Let us continue this discussion in chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136287/discussion-between-michael-albanese-and-phi)

Answer (score 0):

The first isomorphism $H^{1}(X,\mathbb{Z}/2) \cong \text{Hom}( H_{1}(X),\mathbb{Z}/2)$ follows by the universal coefficient theorem.

The second isomorphism follows since for any group $G$ we have $\text{Hom}(G,\mathbb{Z}/2) \cong \text{Hom}(G_{\text{ab}},\mathbb{Z}/2).$

I can't help you with part (3) as I don't know any of that theory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. About the universal coefficient theorem, I can see from this book https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf, page 195 (whole pdf page 204), theorem 3.2, there is a cochain, but why it is an isomorphism?

Comment: because $H_0$ is always a free group. Part 3 is right as well. Intuitively, the first stiefel whitney class can be detected by looking at a  loop $S^1 \to X$, pulling back the vector bundle and checking to see if its determinant bundle is a mobius band or a cylinder.